# Generate Code dynamically using a Template

Tags: c#, templates, text

I'm looking for some help when it comes to dynamically generating Code form a template.

The template will be filled with previously imported data that needs to replace placeholders.

**Edit:** The generated Code does not need to be compiled. It will be used in another program. The generation get triggered by user inputs.

The issue here is that there can be more than one attribute for example. The attributes need to have their own Template again. That again could contain a keyword for the comment template and so on (there is no loop possible). The Comments are bound to either an attribute or the class itself, that means there has to be a way to separate the two.

This is the custom template I'm using:
**Edit2:** This is only an example, the generated code does not need to be C# it can be whatever the User chooses as the template.

```
###File
using System;

namespace {Namespace}
{
    internal class {Classname}{Base}{Comment}
    {
        //Basic Attributes
{Attributes}

        //Structured Attributes
{Structuredattributes}
    }
}
###

###Attributes
        internal {Datatype} {Attributename} { get; set; }{Comment}      
###

###Base
 : {Basename}
###

###Comment
 // {Commentdata}
###
```

Explanation:

```
{Word} is a placeholder. All Placeholders are predefined (for now)
###Word is the start, Word is the ID. That means this block defines a placeholders look.
### is the end
```

Currently I work with the Replace(Placeholder, data)-Function, but that doesn't seem like a nice solution.

I need a template so that a user can simply write a new Exportformat without touching code at all.
The user can completely define the looks aswell. All the spaces and lines will be placed aswell.

Maybe someone has a great idea and can push me in the right direction. I wouldn't mind changing the template format but I need good readability of the replacement.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use _T4 Templates_?

Comment: I didn't know about T4, but from what I saw it requires the template to include code. That would be an issue as the user shouldn't write code and should only supply the template.